# Finding roots by solving its ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

Roots of fluctuating function (p,q real) needed to evaluate eigenvalues of

$$ y(x) = \dfrac{\sin px }{p}  + \dfrac {\sin q x }{q} =0 ...(1*) $$

form a real and complex infinite set. The way to capture/collect  them all in a defined interval seems (to me) involved with uncertainties of sequentially ordering them through straight algorithmic procedures.( Referring to the first tangent intersection of Newton-Raphson straying off way too far).

In a proposed workaround since in Rootfinding,its derivatives are anyways involved together ..

Does it in someway shorten/speed up /facilitate/ improve calculation efficiency  of the procedure if instead we choose to NDSolve that associates derivatives of the functions?

In this particular case

$$ y^{''} + q^2 y + \sin p x \cdot( p^2- q^2)  /p =0  ...(2*) $$ which is same as

$$ y^{''} + p^2 y - \sin q x \cdot( p^2- q^2)  /q = 0 $$

Implied advantage is,ready availability of successive derivative algorithms  associated with solution of differential equations.

EDIT1:

Is it easier/effective to attempt to find all roots for the *straight closed* form $y(x) $ in (1*), or to try to find solutions for the *derived ODE* function (2*)?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following you. Could you explain further?

Comment: I'm sure I'm not following. Do `p` and `q` have numerical values? If not, what does it mean to find solutions in an interval?

Comment: It seems you're saying that this doesn't work satisfactorily: `With[{p = 12, q = 5, a = 0, b = 5}, NSolve[{Sin[p x]/p + Sin[q x]/q == 0, a <= Re[x] <= b}, x]]` But it seems ok to me.  Or perhaps your question is about the mathematics (numerics) of equation solving?  Then you should ask on a different site.

Comment: @ DanielLichtblau ;  p = 0.756 ; q = 1.12;
Plot[Sin[ p x]/p + Sin[q x]/q, {x, 0, 70}]
There are 16 real roots and complex roots with real  part near  to 9, 26, 44, 60 . Can we get them all in a table?

Comment: @Micheal E2: I had given the command you indicated and all roots are getting reported exactly as I had wished for in a line, Thanks for the same! The question remains if I I use solution obtained by NDSolve for (2*), do we have all the roots lined up this way too?

Comment: I don't understand how to use `NDSolve` to find all the real and complex roots in a given range -- I didn't know it was possible.  Could you post the code you're using?  (Side remark: If you desire the roots in order, you can always use `Sort`, if you find that the solutions are returned out of order.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 For real roots one can use event handling in `NDSolve` (but you probably knew that). For complex roots? Maybe set up as PDE using CR equations, with event handlers involving real and imaginary parts? It would be interesting to know if there is an approach along those or other `NDSolve` lines.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I don't think it's an easy matter to detect a zero-crossing in ${\Bbb C} \cong {\Bbb R}^2$, as it is in ${\Bbb R}$.  But there's a lot I don't know.  Perhaps there is a way to quickly approximate the number of zeros in a rectangle $D$ with $n = \int_{\partial D} f'(z)/f(z) \; dz / (2 \pi i)$.